# composition series of a group algebra over finite field

Tags: representation-theory

Assume F is a finite field of characteristic 2 and G is the Klein's four-group. How many different composition series does the FG F-algebra have, as a module over itself? Is this number related somehow with the cardinality of F?

Comment: The algebra has dimension $4$, so there are not that many possibilities. Are you familiar with the possible dimensions of representations of this group in characteristic $2$?

Comment: it is a small ring indeed. however i cannot understand how is this related with the cardinality of the field

Comment: Sorry, my first comment was based on a misread, where I thought it was just the field of $2$ elements rather than an arbitrary finite field of characteristic $2$.

Comment: my problem is that i never read any correlation between the cardinality of a field and number of composition series.

Comment: You should not be thinking in terms of the cardinality of the field so much. What is important is whether you can apply Schur's lemma. Also, when do you consider two composition series to be the same? Do they have to consist of the same submodules?

Comment: yes, in this context two composition series are the same if they have the same submodules.

Comment: Ok, then probably the answer will indeed also depend on the cardinality, as increasing that will generally provide more ways to choose submodules. I will need to think more about that.

Comment: what can we say about the FG-submodules of FG in that case? Do you have any idea about that?

Comment: Well, the irreducible modules are all trivial, so you are looking for elements on which the group acts trivially. One obvious choice is the sum of the elements of the group (I am not sure if there are more).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$FG$ has a unique simple submodule $S$, spanned by $\sum_{g\in G}g$, and a unique maximal submodule $J=\left\{\sum_{g\in G}a_gg\vert \sum_{g\in G}a_g=0\right\}$, and $G$ acts trivially on the quotient $J/S$.

So every composition series of $FG$ has the form
$$0<S<M<J<FG$$

for some $2$-dimensional submodule $M$ of $J$ containing $S$. Choosing $M$ is equivalent to choosing a $1$-dimensional submodule of $J/S$, and since $G$ acts trivially on $J/S$, every subspace of $J/S$ is a submodule.

So the number of composition series is the number of $1$-dimensional subspaces of a $2$-dimensional vector space over $F$, which is $\vert F\vert+1$.

Comment: Thank you very much Jeremy, only one question. i understand the whole solution, except one part. Why G acts trivially on the quotient?

Comment: @mayer_vietoris It's just a calculation. Let the elements of $G$ be $1,x,y,xy$. Then $J/S$ is spanned by $1+x$ and $1+y$, and $(1+x)x=x+x^2=1+x$ and $(1+y)x=x+xy=(1+y)+(1+x+y+xy)$, which is $1+y$ modulo $S$. So $x$ acts trivially on $J/S$. Similarly $y$ does too.

Comment: SO, it's not that the above is always true? happens to be true in this particular case? Due to Wallace there exist a way to describe the Jacobson radical of a ring but it's not true that G acts always trivial on J/S for any given finite-dimensional algebra.

Comment: @mayer_vietoris Yes, this is very special to this particular case. For almost all other algebras, $J/S$ will be far more complicated than this.